# iOS 9 Swift, UITextView Height based on the Content

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have been trying to find a way to adjust the height of the UItextview all over the place but could not find an answer. So, I am asking for your help. I am not using a storyboard to make constraints. How do you make the height of UITextView dynamic based on the content size? Thank you for your help! I have attached an image to show how the textview looks like.

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iijO.png)

```
 scrollView.addSubview(itemTitleView)
        itemTitleView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(itemImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 80).active = true
        itemTitleView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(itemImage.widthAnchor).active = true
        itemTitleView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(56).active = true
        itemTitleView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
```

Comment: It would be easier if it was a label. Because it has intrinsic height and width. If it is not editable you can use UILabel instead of textView.

Comment: is your textview editable? Or just for display purposes only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this extension for string. This will give you the height you need if you know what the width will be.  You just need the width and the font and it should work.

```
extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)

        let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```